# OneDrive sdk - how to share files/folders programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone, onedrive

I'm writing an app (for windows phone 8) that needs to create a folder in OneDrive and set permissions to share it with selected contacts and make this folder visible on those users 'Shared' section.

Is there a way to do so programmatically with the OneDrive SDK rather than REST service?

The use of links creation to files/folder is not suitable for my purpose ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631815.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders ).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why sharing links aren't sufficient for your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Share edit and read links are currently our only supported scenario for sharing.